# How can I add another line to an existing line - using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, selenium-webdriver, codemirror

Problem: 
I am writing some functional tests using Selenium - C#. 
I have to add two CSS lines in the code-mirror textarea. It seems like I can only do it using Javascript in my C# code by targeting the main "div" with class = CodeMirror. i.e. [shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaXTu.jpg)

But when I do it using this code:

```
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver;

        string ExistingCSS=null;

        for (int i = 0; i < table.RowCount; i++)
        {
            ScrollIntoView(Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CodeMirror")));
            ExistingCSS = ExistingCSS + Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CodeMirror")).FindElements(By.ClassName("CodeMirror-line"))[i].Text;
            Console.WriteLine(" Existing CSS -> "+ ExistingCSS);

            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(\"" + ExistingCSS + table.Rows[i]["CssValue"] + "\")", Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CodeMirror")));

        };
```

It adds the lines but next time when I run the same code, it overrides what was written in that code-mirror textarea.

Help?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Where is your `ExistingCSS` ??

Comment: ExistingCSS is set to Null at the begining of the execution, but after the first iteration in the loop: value will be CSS Code which will be pasted from another file
OUTPUT : 
1st iteration -> Existing CSS -> 
2nd iteration ->  Existing CSS -> div.questframe {    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;    -moz-border-radius: 40px;    : 40px;}

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(" Existing CSS -> "+ ExistingCSS);` what is printed in your console ?

Comment: This: 
Existing CSS -> 
 Existing CSS -> div.questframe {    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;    -moz-border-radius: 40px;    : 40px;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing a small "hack"
 - I found the Textarea which had style.display = none.
 - I changed its value to Block: `js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('CustomCssArea').style.display = 'block'");` -> so it was visible.
 - Then i simply sent CSS values to that textarea by using "element.SendKeys("CSS Values here...");

Answer (score 0):

```
ExistingCSS = ExistingCSS + Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CodeMirror")).FindElements(By.ClassName("CodeMirror-line"))[i].Text;
```

Change your above line as below:

```
ExistingCSS += ExistingCSS + Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CodeMirror")).FindElements(By.ClassName("CodeMirror-line"))[i].Text;
```

Comment: nope didnt work - same result as before.
Output to the codemirror textarea is : 
`div.questframe {    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;    -moz-border-radius: 40px;    : 40px;}.NextBackSendButtons input {    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;    -moz-border-radius: 40px;    border-radius: 40px;}`